# can only concatenate str (not "numpy.int64") to str

Tags: python, concatenation, typeerror

So I am still new to python and cant figure out how to fix this command

```
unique_flag2=[string3 + x for x in unique_flag]
```

when I run it I keep getting this error

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.int64") to str
```

can anyone help ?

Comment: Might have to convert to a string. Try: `unique_flag2 = [string3 + str(x) for x in unique_flag]`

Comment: Please post a complete program that reproduces the error. See [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Cast the non-string operand to string using `str`:

```
unique_flag2=[string3 + str(x) for x in unique_flag]
```

Comment: brilliant I will give it a go and see what happens :)